# php-fpm stop responding pool seems busy

Tags: php

php-fpm crash every morning at 7pm (I don't have specific cron at this time), log say :

```
 WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 39 idle, and 180 total children
```

Server hardware :

```
nproc : 40
RAM: 256Go
```

here is www.conf of php-fpm :

```
[www]

user = www-data
group = www-data

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0666

listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 350
pm.start_servers = 40
pm.min_spare_servers = 40
pm.max_spare_servers = 70
pm.process_idle_timeout = 60s;
pm.max_requests = 500

request_terminate_timeout = 0

chdir = /

php_flag[display_errors] = off
php_admin_value[error_reporting] = 0
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 1024M
php_admin_value[session.save_path] = /tmp/
```

I already try to increase max_children value but it change nothing